# Connection closed while trying to POST

Tags: rest, qt, post, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am new at QT and I am trying to establish REST service (GET and POST) for my application. Meanwhile GET demand works fine, I can not execute POST demand (as result I got from server reply: Connection closed error). Do you have any suggestions what is wrong?

Constructor:

```
{
    net_acc_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(net_acc_manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,this, &MyApp::httpFinished);
}
```

POST, response I get: Failed, error code #2. Server error explanation: Connection closed

```
void MyApp::Post_demand()
{
    QUrl url = QUrl("http://192.168.2.1/od/6040/00");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    QByteArray postdata="0000";
    net_acc_manager->post(request,postdata);
    qCDebug(log_hal) << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Request POST posted" << full_url.toString();
}
```

GET, that part works fine, output:  Http post finished successfully.

```
void MyApp::Get_demand()
{
    QUrl url = QUrl("http://192.168.2.1/od/6040/00");
    reply=net_acc_manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://192.168.2.1/od/6040/00")));
    qCDebug(log_hal) << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Request GET posted" << full_url.toString();
}
```

HttpFinished function

```
void MyApp::httpFinished(QNetworkReply *n_reply)
{

    qCDebug(log_hal) << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Http request finished. Status code:" << n_reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();

    if (n_reply->error()) {
        qCCritical(log_hal) << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Status code:" << n_reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
        qCCritical(log_hal) << Q_FUNC_INFO <<
                       QString("Failed, error code: #%1; Server error explanation: %2")
                       .arg(QString::number(n_reply->error())
                            , n_reply->errorString().replace(QRegExp("\%20"), " ")).toLatin1().data();

        n_reply->deleteLater();
        n_reply = Q_NULLPTR;
        emit failed();
        return;
    }

    qCDebug(log_hal) << QString("Http post finished successfully. Reply Text: %1\nElapsed time: %2 ms")
                         .arg(QString(n_reply->readAll()), QString::number(timer->elapsed())).toLatin1().data();

    //dummy read, to clear buffer
    n_reply->readAll();

    n_reply->deleteLater();
    n_reply = Q_NULLPTR;
    emit finished();
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the customer is the cause of the error? Maybe the problem is with the server.

Comment: Because REST service (POST and GET) works fine while using CURL in terminal or postman, but not in QT (in QT at the moment only GET demand works).

example for CURL demand:
post:  curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -i 'http://192.168.2.1/od/6040/00' --data '"0000"'
get: curl -X GET -i 'http://192.168.2.1/od/6040/00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after all, I have found the problem and solution. It appeared that the problem was at posting string at POST demand.

The line from POST function:

```
QByteArray postdata="0000";
```

Should actually be:

```
QByteArray postdata("\"0000\"");
```

Thanks anyway.